# Extracting JSON from page source in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape product information from a website and have found I need to extract JSON from the "script" tag in the main body of the page_source, which I've gotten via selenium (returns a string). It has to be the page_source because the products are loaded after the page, so requests hasn't worked.

link is here: view-source:https://centralsquare.dailytable.org/category/fruits_and_veggies_fresh_fruits

I've tried adding .json() to the returned page_source, but since it's a string I can't do that. I would like to avoid messy string splitting and concatenation, if possible.

Comment: Have you picked out the lines like `var ProductCard1...` from the html source? You can get them with the requests packackage so selenium is likely not required. Having identified those lines, it should be possible to pick out the json text via regex and load it.

Comment: You can convert [json string to Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) using json.loads(json_string)

Comment: @DanielSabrel this gave me this error:

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @JonSG selenium is required to get the page source--the products aren't available on the html

Comment: If you do a view source I see `var ProductCard1_5452931_649f1e4adeea5_props = {"id":"5452931","loading":false,"mode":"weight","upc":"4408","storeSlug":"daily-table-central-square","productPageUrl":"\/store\/daily-table-central-square\/product\/4408","priceBeforeDiscount":null,"price":1.99,"priceFull":"$1.99","discountInfo":"","title":"Asian Pears"....};` that looks like the data for the first product without selenium to me.

Comment: @JonSG how are you doing a view source without selenium, though? .page_source doesn't exist on requests.

Comment: Using chrome you can visit the page and then view source that will give you the raw source of the page, same as you get via regests.get

Answer (score 1):

To get the data from the `<script>` tag you can use `re` module (some additional parsing is necessary though):

```py
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://centralsquare.dailytable.org/category/fruits_and_veggies_fresh_fruits?page={page}&per-page=24'

all_data = []
for page in range(1, 3):
    html_doc = requests.get(url.format(page=page)).text

    for p in re.findall(r'var ProductCard\S+_props = (.*);', html_doc):
        p = re.sub(r'"[^"]+":ProductCard[^,\s]+,?', '', p)
        all_data.append(json.loads(p))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         id  loading    mode       upc                   storeSlug                                      productPageUrl priceBeforeDiscount  price priceFull discountInfo                                    title                                                                                                                                                                 product_image  count product_price_units volume_units volume  quantity_in_pack  quantityInitial  quantityStep discount  quantityMin  quantityMax      category  haveModifications modificationsIcon  canAddByWeight  approxWeight    theme proportions corners  hasBackground background                                                                                                                                                        tags  hidePrice  openSignInPopup       brand
0   5452931    False  weight      4408  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4408                None   1.99     $1.99                                           Asian Pears                                              https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/yecWbpJvIiOiLn1WaXZzV3kjYvIjZmNyNvY2YTNwIDcjN5gq5CN0LicGcXazJCpjIlpicnI7M2MjOCaiwCYzM6I=0Xfw.jpg      0                  lb                                   NaN              1.0          0.25     None         0.25          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
1   5452934    False  weight      4223  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4223                None   0.99     $0.99                                              Avocados          https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/JyeicWbpavIiO2Ln1W9Gctlz9Cdybl1WYSZtFm9mcQ9lNWdkZyZ0L0XoNXlWdyZM9yc0ZnJXYmdB9VRWYj9wpmLvIsIyZmepNnsnOiU6IydiLwYzMjIoJCBjNzo==Qf9.jpg      0                each                                   1.0              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
2   5452960    False  weight      4011  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4011                None   0.39     $0.39                                               Bananas          https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/JyeicWbpavIiO2Ln1W9Gctlz9Cdybl1WYSZtFm9mcQ9lNWdkZyZ0L0XoNXlWdyZZ9yc0bsxWZmQfd35WYuFwpmLhIsIyZmepNnsnOiU6IydiLwYzMjIoJCBjNzo==Qf9.jpg      0                  lb                                   1.0              1.0          0.25     None         0.25          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
3   5453084    False  weight      4056  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4056                None   2.99     $2.99                                 Black Seedless Grapes                                              https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/yecWbpJvIiOiLn1WaXZzV3RWZvIwUDNhMvQTNTM2QTUDOxUq5iM4LicGcXazJCpjIlpicnI7M2MjOCaiwCYzM6I=0Xfw.jpg      0                  lb                                   1.0              1.0          0.25     None         0.25          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
4   5453088    False  weight      4240  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4240                None   3.99     $3.99                                   Blueberries (11 oz)                                                      https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/pJyeOicWbWavIiV3Ln1vIXZzO0YWNzYkFDNTN5Yq5yMhInVGc2ciwiISZ6l3Jye6NzojImIsAjMjOig91HM2.jpg      0                each           oz     11               1.0              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False  Driscoll's
5   5453110    False  weight      4319  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4319                None   2.89     $2.89                                      Cantaloupe Melon                                                      https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/pJyeOicWbWavIiV3Ln1vIXZzZ0YWNWO0IWQTMjFq5iZ4InVGc2ciwiISZ6l3Jye6NzojImIsAjMjOig91HM2.jpg      0                each                                   1.0              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
6   5453142    False  weight      3384  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/3384                None   5.99     $5.99                                Clementines (3 lb bag)                                              https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/yecWbpJvIiOiLn1WaXZzV3kjYvIjZmNyMvY2YTM4YTAzN1Iq5CMxLicGcXazJCpjIlpicnI7M2MjOCaiwCYzM6I=0Xfw.jpg      0                each           lb      2               1.0              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
7   5453301    False  weight      4131  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4131                None   1.59     $1.59                                           Fuji Apples      https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/yecWbpJvIiOiLn1WaGctl29Cdy9l1WYzZtFmbmcQ9SNWdk9yZ0LlXoNXZWdyZ09yc0lppWdGcwF0X0XlxGV0X5Jug2YhInBna2ciwiISZ6l3Jye6NzojImIsAjMjOig91HM2.jpg      0                  lb                                   1.0              1.0          0.25     None         0.25          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
8   5453305    False  weight      4135  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4135                None   1.29     $1.29                                           Gala Apples          https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/JyeicWbpavIiO2Ln1W9Gctlz9Cdybl1WYSZtFm9mcQ9lNWdkZyZ0L0XoNXlWdyZQ9yc0Xr5WaHZhx0BXQfluUGbwInBna2ciwiISZ6l3Jye6NzojImIsAjMjOig91HM2.jpg      0                  lb                                   1.0              1.0          0.25     None         0.25          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
9   5453344    False  weight      4139  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4139                None   1.59     $1.59                                   Granny Smith Apples                                              https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/yecWbpJvIiOiLn1WaXZzV3kjYvIjZmNyMvY2YTOzIzgDNzgq5CMyLicGcXazJCpjIlpicnI7M2MjOCaiwCYzM6I=0Xfw.jpg      0                  lb                                   NaN              1.0          0.25     None         0.25          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
10  5453346    False  weight  47d71c63  daily-table-central-square  /store/daily-table-central-square/product/47d71c63                None   1.29     $1.29                                            Grapefruit                                                      https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/pJyeOicWbWavIiV3Ln1vIXZzZ0YWNGZzIWMjN1Yq5iM1InVGc2ciwiISZ6l3Jye6NzojImIsAjMjOig91HM2.jpg      0                each                                   1.0              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
11  5453357    False  weight      4024  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4024                None   1.49     $1.49                                           Green Pears  https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/eWbpJyIiOicn1Wavctl2LCdy9G1WYz9tFmblcQ9SZWdk9mZ0LlNoNXZydyZ0Xyc0lWFWbT9C9Fbsb0JXYFd0VGFWZQ9q5ycyLicGcXazJCpjIlpicnI7M2MjOCaiwCYzM6I=0Xfw.jpg      0                  lb                                   1.0              1.0          0.25     None         0.25          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
12  5453359    False  weight      4498  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4498                None   1.49     $1.49                                 Green Seedless Grapes          https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/JyeicWbpavIiO2Ln1W9Gctlz9Cdybl1WYSZtFm9mcQ9lNWdkZyZ0L0XoNXlWdyZH9yc0blVmcmcH9lMXZwFwpmLxIsIyZmepNnsnOiU6IydiLwYzMjIoJCBjNzo==Qf9.jpg      0                  lb                                   1.0              1.0          0.25     None         0.25          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
13  5453400    False  weight      4030  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4030                None   0.59     $0.59                                                  Kiwi                                              https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/yecWbpJvIiOiLn1WaXZzV3kjYvIjZmNyMvY2YTO3ATUDMwQq5CN5LicGcXazJCpjIlpicnI7M2MjOCaiwCYzM6I=0Xfw.jpg      0                each                                   NaN              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
14  5453420    False  weight      4958  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4958                None   0.49     $0.49                                                Lemons                                              https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/yecWbpJvIiOiLn1WaXZzV3gjNvI1UGM2MvMWNDO3YjgzNwgwpmLxIsIyZmepNnsnOiU6IydiLwYzMjIoJCBjNzo==Qf9.jpg      0                each                                   NaN              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
15  5453426    False  weight      4048  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4048                None   0.35     $0.35                                                 Limes                                              https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/yecWbpJvIiOiLn1WaXZzV3gjNvI1UGM2MvMWNjMzYzcTNzcq5SN4LicGcXazJCpjIlpicnI7M2MjOCaiwCYzM6I=0Xfw.jpg      0                each                                   1.0              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
16  5453437    False  weight      3389  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/3389                None   0.39     $0.39               Mandarin Oranges / Stem & Leaf Satsumas                                                      https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/pJyeOicWbWavIiV3Ln1vIXZzZ0YWNGN1UDQjNyIq5iN4InVGc2ciwiISZ6l3Jye6NzojImIsAjMjOig91HM2.jpg      0                  lb                                   1.0              1.0          0.25     None         0.25          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
17  5453438    False  weight      4959  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4959                None   0.99     $0.99                                               Mangoes                                              https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/yecWbpJvIiOiLn1WaXZzV3kjYvIjZmNyMvY2YDN0IjUDM5EwpmL1IsIyZmepNnsnOiU6IydiLwYzMjIoJCBjNzo==Qf9.jpg      0                each                                   1.0              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
18  5453455    False  weight      3107  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/3107                None   0.69     $0.69                                         Navel Oranges                                              https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/yecWbpJvIiOiLn1WaXZzV3UTOvIlVzN3MvEGZjM4gjQjN5Eq5SNxLicGcXazJCpjIlpicnI7M2MjOCaiwCYzM6I=0Xfw.jpg      0                each                                   NaN              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
19  5453464    False  weight      4395  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4395                None   1.29     $1.29                                               Papayas                                              https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/yecWbpJvIiOiLn1WaXZzV3kjYvIjZmNyMvY2YDOzIzIDM3cq5CO0LicGcXazJCpjIlpicnI7M2MjOCaiwCYzM6I=0Xfw.jpg      0                  lb           lb                      NaN              2.5          1.00     None         2.50          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
20  5453472    False  weight      4430  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4430                None   2.49     $2.49                                             Pineapple                                              https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/yecWbpJvIiOiLn1WaXZzV3kjYvIjZmNyMvY2YTN3IzgjMzAq5iM3LicGcXazJCpjIlpicnI7M2MjOCaiwCYzM6I=0Xfw.jpg      0                each                                   NaN              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
21  5453475    False  weight      4235  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4235                None   0.59     $0.59                                             Plantains                                              https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/yecWbpJvIiOiLn1WaXZzV3kjYvIjZmNyMvY2YDM0YTczMwUq5iM3LicGcXazJCpjIlpicnI7M2MjOCaiwCYzM6I=0Xfw.jpg      0                each                                   NaN              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
22  5453537    False  weight      4054  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4054                None   3.99     $3.99                                           Raspberries                                                      https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/pJyeOicWbWavIiV3Ln1vIXZzZ0YWNGNhVDljMkVq5SZhInVGc2ciwiISZ6l3Jye6NzojImIsAjMjOig91HM2.jpg      0                each           oz      6               1.0              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
23  5453545    False  weight      4635  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4635                None   1.49     $1.49                                   Red Seedless Grapes                                              https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/yecWbpJvIiOiLn1WaXZzV3FzMvIxMTMlMvQzYzN2MjQDM1Iw5CM1LicmbXazJCpjIlpicnI7M2MjOCaiwCYzM6I=0Xfw.jpg      0                  lb                                   1.0              1.0          0.25     None         0.25          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
24  6102547    False  weight      4323  daily-table-central-square      /store/daily-table-central-square/product/4323                None   3.49     $3.49                                          Strawberries                                                      https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/pJyeOicWbWavIiV3Ln1vIXZzZ0YWNWMlVDUjY2Eq5SY5InVGc2ciwiISZ6l3Jye6NzojImIsAjMjOig91HM2.jpg      0                each           lb      1               1.0              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
25  6801843    False  weight  cb61fbcb  daily-table-central-square  /store/daily-table-central-square/product/cb61fbcb                None   3.49     $3.49                                          Blackberries                                                      https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/pJyeOicWbWavIiV3Ln1vIXZzM5AjNjZwUmMzYlRq5SO5InVGc2ciwiISZ6l3Jye6NzojImIsAjMjOig91HM2.jpg      0                each           oz      6               NaN              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff                                                                                                                                                          []      False            False            
26  8019591    False  weight  23ecd3f4  daily-table-central-square  /store/daily-table-central-square/product/23ecd3f4                None   1.99     $1.99                                   Personal Watermelon                                  https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/pJyeOicWbWavIiN3Ln1lJ3b0byB3X3Y1R2JlUvQN1CUWN6FUMyVtIHFWbp9q5SZnLicGcXazJCpjIlpicnI7M2MjOCaiwCYzM6I=0Xfw.jpg      0                each                   1               NaN              1.0          1.00     None         1.00          100  Fresh Fruits              False              None           False             0  theme_1      square   sharp          False    #ffffff  [{'id': '116', 'icon': 'https://cdn.localexpress.io/img/JyeicWbpavIiO2Ln1Wl2clRw9lbnLldWYWZVRzlWYSJFVXevavcTa2Zh1WBnauU=0nIn.jpg', 'title': 'Hot Deals!'}]      False            False
```

Answer (score 0):

I open this website in edge until it loaded, it takes so much time, rightclick and view the page source. this is the page looks like.
`var ProductCard10_5453344_64a009c3699ef_props = {"id":"5453344","loading":false,"mode":"weight","upc":"4139","storeSlug":"daily-table-central-square","productPageUrl":"\/store\/da`

you are looking for product information, above is what I found. maybe you can use string method to parse.